# Battery Impact: Idle vs Busy Websocket on iOS

Tags: ios, websockets

I’m wondering whether a busy websocket connection uses significantly more battery on iOS than a sparsely utilized one - or if there is a constant overhead simply for maintaining the connection that dominates. This will inform some architectural decisions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to this research paper: [HTML5 Connectivity Methods and Mobile Power Consumption](https://www.w3.org/2012/10/Qualcomm-paper.pdf), you *do* consume a significant amount of energy maintaining an inactive websocket, because it is sending frequent messages back and forth to keep the connection alive. Ideally, you would send data at an interval where the websocket could utilize power-saving mechanisms such as "Fast Dormancy" or if the data is sent sporadically, use stateless AJAX requests with a self defined polling frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't quite answer my question though: in my use case, we have a single socket open. My question is whether the battery drain from that one socket will be significantly different if that websocket is streaming data consistently, versus streaming only sporadically.

Comment: @MichaelPiazza Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Whoever downvoted this to "-1" needs to rethink their life. Even if OP doesn't think his question is answered, as far as possible answers go this one is on the mark, even pointing to a good paper. It is as good as can be expected given the question. Some people need to educate themselves on the purpose of downvotes on this site! And by the way, I don't understand how this does _not_ answer your question, @MichaelPiazza. I hope it wasn't you who downvoted. Your question **cannot** be answered more concretely, it is too unspecific and too broad.